# Domo - Detailed Dataview Duplicates

Tags: user-interface, duplicates, data-visualization, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, domo

We are running DOMO on top of Snowflake DB. My problem relates to a detailed view of a card, something like this:

[DOMO data view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cif9C.jpg)

https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/1998/8P7Azo.jpg

To get this results displayed, DOMO runs a DB query which looks something like this:

```
SELECT <columns>
FROM <the table>
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 50
```

If the dataset is bigger than 50 rows, you need to scroll down using the slide bar to get the another 50 rows loaded into the DOMO view:

[DOMO sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVcnw.jpg)

https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/9928/iRRkjJ.jpg

Now, when you do that, the DOMO engine runs **exactly** the same query as above to retrieve the rows.

```
SELECT <columns>
FROM <the table>
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 50
```

I think you already see my problem, anytime I use the sidebar, it loads 50 random rows from the WHOLE dataset, so eventually, the DOMO view ends up with duplicates or missing rows entirely.

I also know that the SHARE/EXCEL EXPORT button works well, as the LIMIT in that query is rather huge, but I'd like to fix the results in the DOMO view.

Is there any way or a trick how to remedy this issue?